# PLSH: Execute graphic application

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash

I want to execute a graphical X application using PLSH PostgreSQL function. I tried this:

```
create function open() returns text as '
#!/bin/bash
evince /tmp/comprovante.pdf
' language plsh;
```

But, if I try to execute it:

```
select open();
```

It says:

> "ERROR:  open: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
> Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:"

What I need most is to execute xdg-open to show a file (image, PDF etc.) saved in the database and zenity --file-selection to load a file into database.

I am running PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu Desktop with default graphical interface. I usually open the Terminal application and execute psql. I also access it through another Linux computer usign SSH with X Forwarding. I can normally execute "evince" or "zenity" or "xdg-open" through my SSH connection.

### Detailed use case

I have a table like this:

```
create table files_table ( id serial primary key, file bytea not null, extension varchar(10) not null);
```

I expect to open the terminal or ssh connection with X Forwarding, start "psql databasename" and do something like `insert into files_table (file, extension) values read_file();` and it will open zenity, on my current desktop, and ask which file I want to save.

After that, I want to do:  `select openFile(file, extension) from files_table where id = 1;`, and it will open the file saved before with the correct application (using xdg-open), on my current desktop, for instance, it would open the PDF file on evince.

Printscreen of the problem, but is the same.
[image: Printscreen of the problem, but is the same.]

Comment: But `plsh` is running *inside* the database backend isn't it? You don't have a screen to display on from the backend point of view. You will want to do something on your client.

Comment: The error message indicates that the script is running in a context where it does not have access to your graphical environment. You will probably need to add _significantly_ more details about how this is set up and how you expect it to work. Perhaps see https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-the-display-environment-variable/919913#919913 for an outline of the basic concepts.

Comment: It is runnning on my Ubuntu Desktop, but I access it through SSH with X Forwarding too. I'll add that information to the question.

Comment: The command is run _by the PostgreSQL backend_, not the psql client. You may have X forwarding set up for the terminal the client is running in, that doesn't mean you have it set up for the postgresql server.

Comment: In general, this is just a bad idea, and the proper answer is to stop attempting to pursue it at all. Don't ask the server to run a GUI application for you; instead, get it to return a filename to the client, and open `evince` from there.

Comment: (if your system is well-configured, even if you plumb `DISPLAY` through to the server, it'll still have enough security constraints / process isolation to be unable to actually connect to that socket; if you _could_ make this work, it would be evidence that your system's security was sloppy and postgresql isn't running in a process that's as well-isolated as it should be).

Comment: (Locking down the PostgreSQL server process is particularly important because PostgreSQL upstream has as a matter of policy determined that they do not see it as part of their goal to prevent users with access to run arbitrary queries as the postgres superuser from being able to invoke arbitrary commands as the OS-level user that postgres runs as; so to stop someone who has managed to get control of the postgres superuser from having full control of the system that service runs on, it's important to constrain the database server's system account as much as possible).

Comment: Ok. You are right. I will answer the question. Thank you for the advices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea. This should be done outside the PostgreSQL Server for security reasons. More details on Charles Duffy commentaries.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).